# Heroku Website with Google API - Need IP?

Tags: heroku, google-api

I have a website that I wrote with react and pushed to heroku to host it while in development. The website uses the Google API -

When I get the API Key I need to specify the IP address that can get access to the api key. It was easy to put my own ip address in for my local server... but Idk what to put in for a website hosted on heroku. Can you help?

Comment: Heroku uses a very wide range of IP addresses, but this is common. Plenty of hosts have large dynamic blocks of IP addresses. Surely Google's API doesn't require all requests to come from a single IP address to work?

Comment: Thanks! I see that now! Turns out my issue was the clientID stuff was stored in my cache. Clearing my cache made it work.